# Java: How to save user inputs of EditText and TextViews when replacing fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I have fragment (FragmentUpload) containing several textviews and edittext. when user click on upload button (shown in image), user is sent to different fragment where user can chose from the options and the chosen string is displayed in appropriate textviews in Fragment Upload. My problem is when user click on different upload button to chose different string for different textview (from separate fragment), the code do not save the previous value. For instance, when user chooses artist from artist fragment, the textview displays the chosen artist. Now when user click on upload album button to choose album, the code only shows chosen album in textview associated with album but previously chosen string (artist string) is no longer available. please help me ( I am new to android and java)

```js
package com.example.realsungjoen;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Set;

public class FragmentUpload extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private final static int PICK_SONG_REQUEST = 2;
    private Button mBtnChooseImg;
    private Button mBtnUpload;
    private Button mBtnChooseSong;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private ImageView addselectArtists;
    private ImageView addSelectGenre;
    private ImageView addSelectAlbum;
    private ImageView addSelectLanguage;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private TextView mSongFile;
    private TextView selectedArtist;
    private TextView selectedAlbum;
    private TextView selectedGenre;
    private TextView selectedLanguage;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private Uri uriImage;
    private Uri mSongUri;
    private StorageReference mStorageImageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRefArtist;
    private StorageReference mStorageSongRef;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View uploadViews = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container,false);
        mBtnChooseImg = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.btn_chose_img);
        mBtnChooseSong = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_song);
        mBtnUpload = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        cancelButton = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);

        mEditTextFileName = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mSongFile = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.track_file_view);


        mProgressBar = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mImageView = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        addselectArtists = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.addArtist_img);
        addSelectGenre = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.addGenre_img);
        addSelectAlbum = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.addAlbum_img);
        addSelectLanguage = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.addLanguage_img);

        selectedArtist = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.artists);
        selectedAlbum = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.album);
        selectedGenre = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        selectedLanguage = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.language);



        mStorageImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Images");
        mStorageSongRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Songs");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data Uploads");
        mDatabaseRefArtist = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Artists");
        uriImage = Uri.parse("https://media.kasperskydaily.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/92/2019/12/09084248/android-device-identifiers-featured.jpg");


        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        final Toolbar toolbar = uploadViews.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_upload);
        toolbar.setTitle("Upload Songs");
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               MySongFragment mySongFragment = new MySongFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                if (fragment == null){
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, mySongFragment)
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }else {
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mySongFragment)
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }
                ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
        });



        mBtnChooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openImageChooser();

            }
        });
        mBtnChooseSong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSongChooser();
            }
        });

        addselectArtists.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChooseArtistFragment chooseArtistFragment = new ChooseArtistFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, chooseArtistFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        addSelectGenre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //go to choose/select genre here
                ChooseGenreFragment chooseGenreFragment = new ChooseGenreFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container,chooseGenreFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });

        addSelectAlbum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChooseAlbumFragment chooseAlbumFragment = new ChooseAlbumFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, chooseAlbumFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

            }
        });

        addSelectLanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChooseLanguageFragment chooseLanguageFragment = new ChooseLanguageFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container,chooseLanguageFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

            }
        });


        mBtnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadFile();

            }
        });

       cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MySongFragment())
                       .remove(new FragmentUpload())
                       .addToBackStack(null)
                       .commit();
               ViewGroup mContainer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.uploadFragment);
               mContainer.removeAllViews();
               ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
           }
       });
        return uploadViews;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle == null){
            selectedArtist.setText("No Artist Selected");
            selectedGenre.setText("No Genre Selected");
            selectedLanguage.setText("No Language Selected");
            selectedAlbum.setText("No Album Selected");
            return;
        }


        String string = "";
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()){
            string += key;

            switch (string){
                case "artistList":
                    String myValue = bundle.getString("artistList");
                    selectedArtist.setText(myValue);
                    break;
                case "albumList":
                    String myValue1 = bundle.getString("albumList");
                    selectedAlbum.setText(myValue1);
                    break;
                case "langaugeList":
                    String myValue2 = bundle.getString("languageList");
                    selectedLanguage.setText(myValue2);
                    break;
                case "genreList":
                    String myValue3 = bundle.getString("genreList");
                    selectedGenre.setText(myValue3);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void openSongChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_SONG_REQUEST);
    }

    private void openImageChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            mImageUri = data.getData();
           Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).resize(1000,1000).centerCrop().into(mImageView);
           // mImageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);

        }
        if (requestCode == PICK_SONG_REQUEST && resultCode ==Activity.RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            mSongUri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(mSongUri,null,null,null,null);
            int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String mimeType = getFileExtension(mSongUri);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            mSongFile.setText(cursor.getString(nameIndex)+"."+ mimeType);
        }
    }


    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cR = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));

    }
    private void uploadFile(){


        if (mImageUri != null){
            StorageReference fileReferece = mStorageImageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            fileReferece.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);

                                }
                            }, 5000);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Task<Uri> uriTaskImage = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!uriTaskImage.isSuccessful());
                            Uri downloadUriImage = uriTaskImage.getResult();
                            uriImage = downloadUriImage;
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                        }
                    });

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Image File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        if (mSongUri != null){
            StorageReference fileRef = mStorageSongRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
            +"." + getFileExtension(mSongUri));
            fileRef.putFile(mSongUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Track Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Task<Uri> uriTaskSong = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                            while (!uriTaskSong.isSuccessful());
                            Uri downloadUriSong = uriTaskSong.getResult();

                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    downloadUriSong.toString(),uriImage.toString(), selectedArtist.getText().toString().trim());
                            String uploadIdSong = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadIdSong).setValue(upload);

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int)progress);
                        }
                    });
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Song File Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

[refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x73r.jpg)